# Elementary proof of Descartes' theorem (4 mutually tangent circles)

Tags: euclidean-geometry, alternative-proof

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_theorem

How can the Descartes theorem be demonstrated by an elementary method?

Comment: Just invert with center at one of the tangency points. The two circles passing through it will become a pair of parallel lines and the other circles just three tangent circles, tangent to the two lines, and therefore of the same radii. Then prove and use [this formula](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Circular_Inversion#3._General_Formula_for_the_Radius_of_a_Circle_in_Terms_of_the_Radius_of_its_Inverse_Circle) for the radius of a circle and that of its inverse.

Comment: In fact, it is better to see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0101066.pdf) (complex version)